# Is my picture of a website correct?

Tags: web

I tried analyzing what in essence is a website . I thought of deconstructing or reverse engineering a website . The following are the sequence of events, I speculate or theorize the following sequence of events to be taking  place during interaction with a website .

1.Every website is basically a set of computer programs,which get executed when the system where they are stored are contacted .

2.Depending on the processing of the type of request sent by the sender , some xml files , files containing the code to be executed,in response to different events and some script purported for dynamic alteration of the xml files are sent. Out of these xml files .

3. Out of these xml files , one contains the information about the initial appearance of the page and the furnishing of different controls or event generators on the screen .

4.So when some activity is done in the locality of one event generator , like a mouse click , an event is generated .

5. The code snippet to respond to the event is executed . If the code contains contacting the server and sending some request then the server is again pinged .
6. When the server is pinged again , depending on the request sent it again executes some code and in response transfers some more code files ,xml files and scripts to dynamically change the appearance of the page .

Is my understanding about the flow of a website correct ?

Answer (score 0):

A web server is basically just a program sitting on a computer that listens on some TCP port (usually 80 for HTTP, 443 for HTTPS).

Clients (such as browsers) can connect and send a request (in HTTP format) to the server.

The server then sends an HTTP response back.

That's it. That's the basic flow: Connect, request, response.

The response contains a "type" field that tells the client what to do with the data. E.g. it could send an image (which is usually displayed on screen), an audio file (which is played), or a "normal" web page in HTML format.

HTML contains structured information about page content and layout, and may contain references to other resources such as images, style sheets, and scripts. A browser automatically fetches these resources (another HTTP request/response) and processes them.

Scripts can be used to customize the behavior on the client side. These are typically written in JavaScript and make use of an API exposed by the browser for interacting with the current page. They can e.g. register "click" handlers to define what happens when the user clicks on some page element.

XML may or may not be used internally by the web server. It doesn't really matter as far as clients are concerned.

If you want to learn more about this, I suggest researching HTTP, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) has some good articles, for example.

Comment: Can I use this question to ask something more about browser server connectivity or need to raise a separate question ?